# Nhibernate isession.save method throws generic exception error

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I am new to Nhibernate. In my application i get the following exception

```
 NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [PAIRAlertAdmin.VO.TriggerLogVO][SQL: INSERT INTO triggerlog (TriggeredUserID, TriggeredDate, TriggeredMode, TriggeredIP, TriggerDescription) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)] ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
```

The following is the code that generates this error

```
    public void triggerLog(String logDetail, String AlertMode)
    {
        TriggerLogVO triggerLogVO = new TriggerLogVO();
        triggerLogVO.TriggeredUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
        triggerLogVO.TriggeredMode = AlertMode;
        triggerLogVO.TriggeredDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        triggerLogVO.TriggeredIP = BAL.PublicVariablesBAL.RemoteIPAddress;
        triggerLogVO.TriggerDescription = logDetail.ToString(); ;
        iSession.Save(triggerLogVO);
        iSession.Flush();
    }
```

The above function generates the error while saving log information.
This function will be called after long time (say for example 6 to 8 hrs) because that much business rules are checked and executed finally this method called and writing the log information in mysql database table.

On the row where I calll `iSession.Save` it throws the exception.

any help will be appreciated.

Following is my mapping file :

```
<id name="TriggerID" column="ID" type="Int32">
  <generator class="native"></generator>
</id>

<property name="TriggeredUserID" column="TriggeredUserID" type="Int32"></property>
<property name="TriggeredDate" column="TriggeredDate" type="string"></property>
<property name="TriggeredMode" column="TriggeredMode" type="string"></property>
<property name="TriggeredIP" column="TriggeredIP" type="string"></property>
<property name="TriggerDescription" column="TriggerDescription" type="string"></property>
```

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Can you add your nhibernate mapping as well

Comment: Too little information. Where do you open/close session, transaction? Mappings?

Answer (score 1):

When you get a GenericADOException it means that the database could not execute the sql that was supplie to it. I use [Nhibernate Profiler](http://nhprof.com/) to debug things like that. It will show you the sql that it tried to execute. If you run the same sql code against your db you usually get a more detailed exception message.

Comment: if you like the answer you can upvote and/or accept it as an answer :-)

Comment: Thanks to everyone repairing and restarting the MySQL server fixes this issue .